# Understanding the slicing syntax in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an x dimensional matrix in Numpy.  For this example, I will use a 2x2 array.

```
np.array([[2, 2], [3,3]])
```

How would I alternate adding a row and column of some value so the result would look like:

```
array([[2, x, 3, x],
       [x, x, x, x].
       [2, x, 3, x],
       [x, x, x, x]])
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27126043/3291506) gives a helpful start by saying to set rows in a correctly-sized destination matrix `b` from a matrix `a` like so `a[::2] = b` but what does the `::2` do in the slicing syntax and how can I make it work on columns?

In short what do the `x` `y` and `z` parameters do in the following: `a[x:y:z]`?

Comment: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) gives a good explanation of what the parameters `x`,`y`,`z` in your example do. In short, `z` is a "step" parameter

Comment: Just as with `range` and `arange`, and list slicing, the parameters are `start`, `stop`, `step`.  `::2` is `slice(None,None,2)`, means every other one.  Try this: `np.arange(0,4,2)`

Comment: @Startec: No.  Rather than shooting in the dark, you should read the above link and do some experiments with small sample arrays (generated by `arange` or `random`).

Comment: `1::2` still gives every other one, starting with 1, i.e. all odds.  Row and column indexing are separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, this should work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[2,2],[3,3]])
b = np.zeros((len(a)*2,len(a)*2))
b[::2,::2]=a
```

This 'inserts' the values from your array (here called `a`) into every 2nd row and every 2nd column

Edit:
based on your recent edits, I hope this addition will help:

`x:y:z` means you start from element `x` and go all the way to `y` (not including `y` itself) using `z` as a stride (e.g. `2`, so every 2 elements, so `x`, `x+2`, `x+4` etc up to `x+2n` that is the closest to `y` possible)
so `::z` would mean ALL elements with stride `z` (or `::2` for every 2nd element, starting from `0`)

You do that for each 'dimension' of your array, so for 2d you'd have `[::z1,::z2]` for going through your entire data, striding `z1` on the rows and `z2` on the columns.

If that is still unclear, please specify what is not clear in a comment.

One final clarification - when you type only `:` you implicitly tell python `0:len(array)` and the same holds for `::z` which implies `0:len(array):z`.
and if you just type `::` it appears to imply the same as `:` (though I haven't delved deep into this specific example)